# git apply changes from one commit onto another branch

Tags: git, rebase, cherry-pick, git-cherry-pick

I want to do something similar to git rebase but without collapsing parallel commits.

Let's say I have the following commits:

```
  B (bar)
 /
A-C-D (foo)
```

Now I want to take the changes that D introduced to C in branch foo, and apply them to B in branch bar. so that I end up with the following:

```
  B-E (bar)
 /
A-C-D (foo)
```

Where the difference between commits B and E is equal to difference between commits C and D. Is this possible? Is there a way to do it without creating a patch?

Comment: I comment the OP for the clarity of this question.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Yes:

```
git checkout -b mergebranch B
git cherry-pick D
```

Comment: To ellaborate on the answer above:

`git checkout -b mergebranch B` creates a new branch called `mergebranch` using branch `B` as the starting point.

`git cherry-pick D` applies the changes introduced by the commit at the tip of the branch `D`.

Comment: Cherry-pick without commit command: `git cherry-pick -n <SHA>`

Comment: A small clarification to the meaning of `B` above. It refers  to a commit hash, in this case the one at the tip of the branch called `bar`, it is not a branch name as it may come across from reading the comment by @Patrick above. This is still the best answer in my humble opinion.

Comment: @EmreTapcı That's what I was searching for, as a normal cherry-pick threw an error despite no affected paths being modified in my worktree. It worked with `-n` and I didn't need a commit anyway.

Answer (score 8):

In my case I needed to apply the changes of specific commits of another branch. I did that by cherry picking them like so:
`git cherry-pick COMMIT-HASH`.

Comment: Note: you need to be in the branch where you want to apply the changes from the commit.

Answer (score 2):

If the last commit on the branch that you want to cherry-pick out of (foo in the example) is a merge commit, you can point at the specific commit to cherry pick by using `git cherry-pick branchname~1` to get the commit which was the parent of the merge.