# Git : Taking changes from one branch + master and applying them to a different branch + master

Tags: git

I am not an expert in git, so I don't know if what I'm looking for is simple or fiendishly complex.

In our repository there are several release branches.  Suppose two of those releases are named v1.0 and v2.0.

Now I have done some changes, let's call them Zog, in a branch that is based on v2.0.  Let's call that v2_zog.  I want to now merge those changes into v1.0, so I have created a branch called v1_zog that is based on v1.0.

To be clear, I only want the changes that I made for v2_zog, relative to v2.0, to be merged into v1_zog.  I don't want to simply merge the whole v2_zog branch into v1_zog, because that will get all the other changes that have been made for v2.

Is there a simple way for this to happen?  I have seen references to cherry picking, and I have been given a procedure for using this route.  But it seems to be that it should be a simple thing to say "Take all the changes that were done for branch X and apply them to branch Y."

Alternatively, is there a way of saying "take all the changes from pull request X and create a pull request to merge them into v2_zog"?

**UPDATE: **  I decided to do the whole thing manually.  There's no good way to do this without being a git expert, and I am not that person.  The process of resolving post-merge errors was going to be much more intensive than just copy & paste.

Comment: Does this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17070293/git-apply-changes-from-one-commit-onto-another-branch) is what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

I think if you only want to apply the change and not the commits, the you can put all of the difference between branch v2 and v2_zog into a patch file

```
git diff v2.0..v2_zog > v2-to-v2_zog.patch
```

and then you can apply the changes from the patch to the v1.0 branch

```
git checkout v1.0
git checkout -b v1_zog
git apply v2-to-v2_zog.patch
```

This will apply the changes in v2_zog relative to v2.0 branch into v1_zog branch but will not make a commit changes, you have to make a new commit as if it is a new change

Additionally, if you want to apply the range of commit made from v2.0 to v2_zog instead, Git 1.7.2 or higher allows you to apply range of commits by using format `git cherry-pick <starting branch>..<ending branch>`

```
git checkout v1.0
git checkout -b v1_zog
git cherry-pick v2.0..v2_zog
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do that is:

```
git rebase v2.0 Zog --onto v1.0
```

That will apply the changes on `Zog` *past* `v2.0` on top of `v1.0`... moving the `Zog` reference position.